# Regex for finding custom URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to create a regex to match URLs that start with http://, https://, // or to find urls that have an extension different from html, htm, php and php3. URL query substrings are optional

Let's say that I want to find these:

```
http://example.com
/example.mp3
/example.mp3?q=example
http://example.com/example.mp3
#example
```

And to reject these:

```
example
/example
/example/
/example.htm
/example.htm?q=example
/example.mp3/example //The .mp3 needs to be extension to be accepted
/example#example
```

I already tried this `/(^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\/\/|#)|(.*)((.*)\.^(?!html|htm|php|php3)$)(\?.*)?$)/igm` but it didn't worked.

If the opposite(reversing the accepted and declined lists) is easier to do, even that is very appreciated, I can change the function that handles the regex.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to find `#example` but not `/example#example`

Comment: Your example and description of accepted parameters is slightly different. Do you want to accept `/` or `//`?

Comment: @Oriol #example can be an anchor to an id in the same page and /example#example can be an anchor to and id in another page

Comment: @wizebin i dont want to accept // (cross-origin) and to accept / (same-origin)

Comment: Try [`^(?:#.+|(?:https?://|/)[^?#]*\.(?:com|mp3)(?:\?.*)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/mM1wUN/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your comment is so close to the solution. mp3 and com were only for example, i want to allow any domain and any extension except html, htm, php and php3. If i enter a domain like .org or an extension like .exe, the regex fails

Comment: Interesting, try the following then: [`^(?:#.+|(?:https?:/)?/[^?#]*\.(?!html?|php3?)\w+(?:\?.*)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/mM1wUN/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much ! It works perfect!

Comment: I enhanced it with a word boundary after the forbidden extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
^(?:#.+|(?:https?:/)?/[^?#\n]*\.(?!(?:html?|php3?)\b)\w+(?:\?.*)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM1wUN/4)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:#.+` - either a `#` followed with any 1+ chars
- `|` - or
- `(?:https?:/)?/[^?#\n]*\.(?!html?|php3?)\w+(?:\?.*)?)` -

  - `(?:https?:/)?/` - an optional `http:/` or `https:/` and then `/`
  - `[^?#]*` - 0+ chars other than `?` and `#`
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?!(?:html?|php3?)\b)\w+` - 1 or more letters/digits/underscore that is not equal to `htm`, `html`, `php` or `php3`
  - `(?:\?.*)?)` - an optional `?` followed with any 0+ chars
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The code seemed a little bit harder at the first sight but the explications made me to understand the code way better.